# Java Generics Bound Mismatch Error

Tags: java, generics

I am writing a generic linked list implementation in Java. The code is

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    private Node<T> top;
    private int no_of_items;

    private class Node<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
        T data;
        Node<T> next;
    }

    public LinkedList() {
        top = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (top == null);
    }

    public void insert(T item) {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>();
        node.data = item;
        node.next = top;
        if(isEmpty()) {
            top = node;
        } else {
            Node<T> n = top; 
            while(n.next != null) {
                n = n.next;
            }
            n.next = node;
        }
        no_of_items++;

    }
}
```

What I want is that `T` should be `Comparable`. While compiling this code I am getting an error where I initialize the Node.

```
Bound Mismatch the type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>> of the type LinkedList<T>.Node<T>
```

I am not able to figure out what is the issue here.

Comment: Don't edit the question with the answer, instead post is as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Since I am a new member, I am not allowed to post answer for my own question for 10 hour hence I edited it. After that time, will post it correctly

Comment: If you have solved your question, then you may mark it as "accepted".  There isn't any reason to add "solved" to your title, as an accepted answer can be seen as equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Makoto for removing Solved. It was initially when i edited with the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error myself. The correct code would be

```
    public class LinkedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
private Node top;
private int no_of_items;

private class Node {
    T data;
    Node next;
}

public LinkedList() {
    top = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (top == null);
}

public void insert(T item) {
    Node node = new Node();
    node.data = item;
    node.next = top;
    if(isEmpty()) {
        top = node;
    } else {
        Node n = top; 
        while(n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = node;
    }
    no_of_items++;

}
    }
```

The answer lies in that when we use a generic type T in a top class and we have non static inner class, the same T is visible in the inner class as well.

Thanks,